# Duplicate Verification In Sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which contains two columns where I'm checking out for duplicates.I have written code for duplicates and it is

```
        DbCommand cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand("SELECT MyTable.* FROM MyTable. INNER JOIN(SELECT MainUrl, COUNT(*) as counter FROM MyTable GROUP BY MainUrl HAVING COUNT(*) >1) t ON t.MainUrl=MyTable.MainUrl");
        int count = db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
        DataSet ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(cmd);
        return ds;
```

Whereas in my columns I have Amazon.com,http://Amazon.com,https://Amazon.com.I want even these two duplicates.I want to return all the columns in my table with those duplicates.But from my code I can't achieve this,Can anyone help me out from this

Comment: what about `https`? do you have that as well in your table? should that also match?

Comment: Yeah I do.See my updated question

Answer (score 1):

Using `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING`:

It considers `'amazon.com'`, `http://amazon.com'`, and  `https://amazon.com'`  as duplicate.

```
WITH MyTable(OriginalURL) AS(
    SELECT 'http://Amazon.com' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'https://Amazon.com' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Amazon.com' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'http://Stackoverflow.com' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Stackoverflow.com' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'http://google.com'
)
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('http://', OriginalURL, 1) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(OriginalURL, 8, LEN(OriginalURL) - 7) 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('https://', OriginalURL, 1) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(OriginalURL, 9, LEN(OriginalURL) - 8) 
        ELSE OriginalURL
    END AS OriginalURL
    , COUNT(*) AS DupeCount
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('http://', OriginalURL, 1) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(OriginalURL, 8, LEN(OriginalURL) - 7) 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('https://', OriginalURL, 1) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(OriginalURL, 9, LEN(OriginalURL) - 8) 
        ELSE OriginalURL
    END
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: I want to represent all those three urls in gridview so I want all those three urls but not as one

Answer (score 0):

Considering one field. We can use this:

```
SELECT field, Count(*) FROM table
GROUP BY field
HAVING Count(*) > 1
ORDER BY Count /*optional DESC*/
```